# strsplit a string into characters, but keeping diagraphs

Tags: r, strsplit

How can I split English words into characters but keeping diagraphs intact (e. g. "ch", "th", "gh")?

For example, for the string "that", I would like to split it into "th", "a", "t", and not "t", "h", "a", "t".

Answer (score 0):

```
strsplit("that", split = "(?<=t(?!h)|th|a)", perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function `f` that may help for splitting

```
dg <- c("ch", "th", "gh", "ai")
v <- c("thanks", "chain", "banana", "that", "rain")

f <- Vectorize(function(s) {
  res <- c()
  while (nchar(s)) {
    k <- ifelse(substr(s, 1, 2) %in% dg, 2, 1)
    res <- c(res, substr(s, 1, k))
    s <- substr(s, k + 1, nchar(s))
  }
  res
})
```

and you will see

```
> f(v)
$thanks
[1] "th" "a"  "n"  "k"  "s" 

$chain
[1] "ch" "ai" "n"

$banana
[1] "b" "a" "n" "a" "n" "a"

$that
[1] "th" "a"  "t"

$rain
[1] "r"  "ai" "n"
```